# Laravel: To pass common parameter value for all route in laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, routes

**  I have Multiple Route in Laravel. I wanna pass common parameter for every Route i,e If i passed POST as a parameter in any route, I need to Call POST controller for all URL.

My Routes are below:

Original URL: www.mydomain.com/home/
Required URL: www.mydomain.com/home/post

Original URL: www.mydomain.com/follow/
Required URL: www.mydomain.com/follow/post

In above URL I have two separate blades like `home.blade.php` AND `post.blade.php`,

In Second Example  I have two separate blades like `follow.blade.php` AND `post.blade.php`. Here `Post.blade.php` is common.

For Both home and follow must call postcontroller. My Route Controllers . **

//for follow Route

```
    Route::get('Follow', [
    'as' => 'Follow',
     'uses' => 'PageController@getFollow' 
]);
```

//for Home Route

```
Route::get('Home', [
    'as' => 'Home',
     'uses' => 'PageController@getHome' 
]);
```

Post Route  controller is below

```
Route::get('Post', [
    'as' => 'Post',
     'uses' => 'PostController@getPOST'
]);
```

Comment: what is wrong with this?`Route::post('follow/post','PageController@getFollow');`

Comment: i want to assign automatically POST control for every Route Which have post as a parameter. no need to mention each and  every URL